# How to relogin and check is session has exired in android?

Tags: android

I have a login feature and when user logs in I am saving the data in Shared Preferences.

In my situation I am uploading data randomly to the server and getting data from the server. I have the login details but I want to know if the session has time out or not so that I login again. Do I relogin or have a timer for the session?

Comment: You mean the session on the server?

Comment: yes the server session timeout is like 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences doesn't have timeout, it will keep in your Application forever until you clear it via:

- clear by programming code > settings.edit().clear();
- manually clear in Application Info in your Android Device

Answer (score 0):

Best (without worrying too much about security) would be to use login tokens in the place of passwords - once the client logs in, return a token that they can store in shared prefs and send back to the server on each ping. Then the server can check if the user is still logged in (i.e. session is still active) and if not, log them back in using the token as verification.

Either that, or (if security really isn't a problem at all) just send the username and password on each ping.